# ERROR: Control may reach end of non-void function /

Tags: c++, function, controls, warnings, void

Don't understand why i'm getting the warning that "Control may reach end of non-void function." Any suggestions?

Here is my code:

```
long double geo_fn(long reps, int seed) {
    double x, y, pythag_sum, total = 0, inside = 0;
    default_random_engine engine(seed);             
    uniform_real_distribution<double>dist(0,1);

    for(int i = 0; i< reps ;i++){
        x = dist(engine);
        y = dist(engine);
        pythag_sum = (x*x)+(y*y);
        if (pythag_sum <= 1){
            inside += pythag_sum;
            total += pythag_sum;
        }
        else {
            total += pythag_sum;
         }
     return (inside/total)/10;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you call the function with a first argument of `0` the loop is never executed and the `return` statement is, thus, never reached. Falling of the end of a non-`void` function is undefined behavior.

My personal guess is that the `return` statement was meant to one level up, i.e., in the out block: this would guarantee that the function always returns a value and the warning would go away.

Answer (score 3):

you have to make sure,regardless of your expectations, that there will be always something to return, since you declared your function return type as non-void.
for this code you will need a return statement that occur in the "else" case

```
Image* Image::findAndClone( imageType type )
{

    if (_prototypes[i]->returnType() == type)
        return _prototypes[i]->clone();

};
```

it will be:

```
Image* Image::findAndClone( imageType type )
{

    if (_prototypes[i]->returnType() == type)
        return _prototypes[i]->clone();
    else return NULL;

};
```

in the case of a "for" loop, there is a chance that the loop will break at "i < _nextSlot" without actually returning anything. The compiler can't tell. so you will need to provide a return statement to capture case where the "for" loop "never executes".

```
Image* Image::findAndClone( imageType type )
{
    for (int i=0; i < _nextSlot; i++)
            return _prototypes[i]->clone();
    return NULL;
};
```

then this is just a final example combining both:

```
Image* Image::findAndClone( imageType type )
{
    for (int i=0; i < _nextSlot; i++)
        if (_prototypes[i]->returnType() == type)
            return _prototypes[i]->clone();
    return NULL;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add an invalid parameter check before the for loop. Making sure that the function will return an error code if one of the parameters passed has an invalid value.